# How to provide context to BlocProvider.of without using BlocBuilder in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

This is my BlocProvider portion of code:

```
late BuildContext _context;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    return BlocProvider<AccountBloc>(
      create: (context) {
        _context = context;
        return AccountBloc();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
```

And inside the onPressed I use this.context:

```
BlocProvider.of<AccountBloc>(this._context)..add(AddAccountEvent(account: account));
```

When I run it the error says:

```
LateInitializationError: Field '_context@30149156' has not been initialized.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `late BuildContext _context;` and wrap your scaffold inside a `Builder` widget. so the provided context is an updated context and you can simply use `BlocProvider.of<AccountBloc>(context)..add(AddAccountEvent(account: account));`

Comment: Don't mind the _formKey sir, I used it in a form. Using a Builder will work. But it's the same as using BlocBuilder. Is there a way to use BlocProvider.of<Bloc>(context)..add(BlocEvent()) without using Builder or BlocBuilder? Thank you.

Comment: i mean remove `late BuildContext _context;` sorry. you can move your scaffold in a separate widget. there is no way else. by the way, what is the problem with Builder?

Comment: Sorry, I thought Builder is the same in BlocBuilder. The reason I don't want to use BlocBuilder because It's main use is when you want to access the state of a bloc.